# there are 2 functions in modelView both are impacting the textview. How to run only one in MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture

```
private fun renderA(state :AViewModel.State?){
        when (state){
            is AViewModel.State.Success -> {
                if (state.description.isNotEmpty()) binding.textView1.text = state.description
            }
            else ->{
            }
        }
    }
private fun renderB(state :BViewModel.State?){
        when (state){
            is BViewModel.State.Success -> {
                if (state.description.isNotEmpty()) binding.textView1.text = state.description
            }
            else ->{
            }
        }
    }
```

Both functions are impacting the `textView1`.
How to stop them from overwriting one another?
Both of them come from different model view and observer.
How to give priority to `renderA`:
If `renderA` happens then `renderB` textview part should not execute in **Clean Code** architecture?

Comment: this looks just horrible in general, you're trying to resolve business logic in your view layer with this. have ONE live data you observe on to and then have your viewmodel determine which value should be set to the text view

Answer (score 0):

```
    private fun renderA(state :AViewModel.State?){
        when (state){
            is AViewModel.State.Success -> {
               setDescription(state.description)
            }
            else ->{
            }
        }
    }

    private fun renderB(state :BViewModel.State?){
        when (state){
            is BViewModel.State.Success -> {
                setDescription(state.description)
            }
            else ->{
            }
        }
    }

fun setDescription(description: String) {
   if(description.isNotEmpty() && binding.textView1.text.isEmpty()){
          binding.textView1.text = description
   }
}
```